# unable to access friend function in template class

Tags: c++, friend, ostream

The Pairwise class represents a pair with a key:value. I've made a template pair and was having errors trying to run with a key and value input to the class and printing it out.

Given my main:

```
#include "file_name.h"

int main (){
    Pairwise<string, string> example = {{"key", "value"}};
    cout << example << endl;
 }
```

And my header file:

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
using std::ostream; using std::cout; using std::endl;
#include<string>
using std::string;
#include<utility>
using std::pair;
#include<sstream>
using std::ostringstream;

template<typename K, typename V>
struct Pairwise{
    K first;
    V second;
    Pairwise() = default;
    Pairwise(K, V);
    //print out as a string in main
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Pairwise &n) {
        ostream oss;
        string s;
        oss << n.first + ":" + n.second; //possible error?
        s = oss.str();
        out << s; 
        return out;
    }
};
```

My expected output after running main would be:

```
key:value
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
h:28:11: error: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits> is protected within..."
```

Comment: That stream inserter is a bit convoluted. `out << n.first << ":" << n.second; return out;` is sufficient. In fact, I'd just write it as a one-liner: `return out << n.first << ':' << n.second;`, but some folks like to be more verbose.

Comment: `ostream oss;` is a typo, right? Should be `ostringstream oss;`. And the error message is truncated. Don't summarize; post the smallest code you can come up with that shows the problem, and quote the **entire** error message. There's nothing protected here, so that bit of the error message needs context in order to make any sense.

Comment: besides it is needlessly complicated ... *`oss << n.first + ":" + n.second;`* – Why `+`? That limits its functionality to types that support `+` for itself and string literals.

Comment: @PeteBecker Awesome, shortened code is always helpful to me!

Comment: @Swordfish Thanks for pointing the '+' operator out. I'm always looking for ways to improve my code. Do you think my main function looks fine as it is? Passing in the values to the template class

Comment: Why the double curly braces? `Pairwise<string, string> example{"key", "value"};` would be sufficient.

Comment: Why do you *`#include<string> using std::string; #include<utility> using std::pair;`* in your header file? `<string>` should be included by the user of that header file if it wants to use `Pairwise` with `std::string`s. And why `<pair>`?

Comment: @Swordfish got it, I have made an edit to my post

Comment: All members are `public`. So, why do you think you would need `friend`?

Comment: Don't edit your posted code on the fly. You **do** need `#include <string>` somewhere, because your `main` function uses `std::string`. **Try it** before you post it.

Comment: @AdrianW I agree with Pete Becker, don't alter the code in the question. Now the error message you included which was caused by your original code makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> h:25:59: friend declaration delares a non template function.

You are missing to declare the function as a template that takes `Pairwise<K, V>`:

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED  /* or pragma once */
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED  /* if you like it */

#include <iostream>  // or <ostream>

template<typename K, typename V>
class Pairwise {  // made it a class so that the
    K first;      // friend actually makes sense.
    V second;

public:
    Pairwise() = default;

    Pairwise(K first, V second)
    : first{ first }, second{ second }
    {}

    template<typename K, typename V>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, Pairwise<K, V> const &p)
    {
        return out << p.first << ": " << p.second;
    }
};

#endif /* HEADER_H_INCLUDED */
```

source file:

```
#include <iostream>  // the user can't know a random header includes it
#include <string>

#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    Pairwise<std::string, std::string> p{ "foo", "bar" };
    std::cout << p << '\n';
}
```

Sidenote: You could also use

```
{
    using Stringpair = Pairwise<std::string, std::string>;
    // ...
    Stringpair sp{ "foo", "bar" };
}
```

if you need that more often.

The other errors you got result from confusing `std::ostringstream` with `std::ostream` in `operator<<()`.

Answer (score 1):

As you write it, you define the operator as a member function, which is very likely not intended. Divide it like ...

```
template<typename K, typename V>
struct Pairwise{
    K first;
    V second;
    Pairwise() = default;
    Pairwise(K, V);
    //print out as a string in main
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Pairwise &n);
};

template<typename K, typename V>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Pairwise<K,V> &n) {
    ...
    return out;
}
```

And it should work.

BTW: Note that in a `struct` all members are public by default; so you would be able to access them even in absence of the `friend`-declaration.

Comment: With the template<typename K, typename V> before the operator

Comment: Isn't there a `template` missing in front of the friend-declaration? e.g `template<typename K, typename V> friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Pairwise<K, V> &n);` ?

Comment: Thank you very much, this cleared up my understanding of friend operator! By the way, could you take a quick glance at my main? If the values are passed in correctly

Comment: *As you write it, you define the operator as a member function* – A definition with `friend` never defines a member.

Comment: @Swordfish is that referring to the warning that "h:25:59: friend declaration delares a non template function...". Do you mind writing in another answer post how you would implement that change? It seems that this causes me to not exactly print out my output "key:value"

Comment: @Dracep *is that referring to the warning that [...]* – yes. I wrote another answer.

Comment: The answer of @Swordfish is much better. If I were you, I'd accept the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

In c++, less is often more...

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<string>

// never do this in a header file:
// using std::ostream; 

template<typename K, typename V>
struct Pairwise{
    K first;
    V second;
    Pairwise() = default;
    Pairwise(K, V);
    //print out as a string in main
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Pairwise &n) {
        return out << n.first << ':' << n.second;
    }
};

int main (){
    using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::string;

    Pairwise<string, string> example = {"key", "value"};
    cout << example << endl;
 }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ZUlLTu